Memory not released on skybox entity
So the issue is on realityView, I'm adding a skybox conditionally, since sometimes I don't want it to show anything, but when the view dismiss, the memory is not released.. everytime I change the contentString, the memory usage stacks.
    var body: some View {
        RealityView { content in
            let rootEntity = Entity()
            rootEntity.addSkybox(for: contentString)
            content.add(rootEntity)
        }
        .transition(.opacity)
    }

    func addSkybox(for destination: String) {
        let subscription = TextureResource.loadAsync(named: destination).sink(
            receiveCompletion: {
                switch $0 {
                case .finished: break
                case .failure(let error): assertionFailure("\(error)")
                }
            },
            receiveValue: { [weak self] texture in
                guard let self = self else { return }
                var material = UnlitMaterial()
                material.color = .init(texture: .init(texture))
                self.components.set(ModelComponent(
                    mesh: .generateSphere(radius: 1E3),
                    materials: [material]
                ))
                self.scale *= .init(x: -1, y: 1, z: 1)
                self.transform.translation += SIMD3<Float>(0.0, 1.0, 0.0)
                
                // Rotate the sphere to show the best initial view of the space.
                updateRotation(for: destination)
            }
        )
        components.set(Entity.SubscriptionComponent(subscription: subscription))
    }


//each time I change string to nil, then change to something else, the memory usage stack up here
    @State var imageSkybox: String? = "Starfield"
    if let imageSkybox = imageSkybox {
                LandscapeImmersiveView(contentString: imageSkybox)
                    .frame(depth: 0)
            }
            

I understand that displaying different skybox content consumes different memory, but even if I set the contentString to nil, the memory has been increase. launch of the app is about 500mb, then I toggle between 2 skybox image and nil by change the string, after 4-5 rounds, the memory has gone up to 1gb. even dismiss immersive space doesn't release that memory..
Anyone have the same issue? or is anyone doing something similar and got a solution to this?

It might be better to create your own material/texture so you can change the parameters programmatically instead of creating and recreating.

Yes, that I understand, but what's the correct way of removing it from memory? even if we replace the material in one immersive session, at some point, we exit immersive space, but that entity is not released from memory?

The fact that it isn’t is likely a bug or an error somewhere. SwiftUI value type nature usually doesn’t allow this to happen but there are circumstances where it does because of leaks. I haven’t tested this code just offered an alternative but the issue could be in many places without an MRE we really can’t fine tune an answer.
